# Whats the status for OSM in print composer QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, printing

I have a Stamen Toner OSM background on a report am doing. It seems impossible to use "Print" or "Save as image" functions since the OSM is being projected wrong with 10 km or so.. Right now I'm taking screenshots from there as a work around but it feels kind of wrong? 
Screenshot with correct OSM projection:
[image: Screenshot with correct OSM projection]

Save from print composer with wrong OSM projection: (Buffers should be located at the lower right corner
[image: Save from print composer with wrong OSM projection]

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly is your question and what are the steps to produce this wrong results?

Comment: I've read that OSM's where not supported in print composer? That's the most recent info I've found at gis.stackexchange so my question is basically if the status has changed or if someone found a way to make it work? The steps are that I've prepared the map with legend and everything looks good in print composer but no matter what I do when I save it or print it from print composer I get the miss-projection of roughly 10 km to the west..